# How to get Map<Id, List<Contact>> from Contact SOQL query GROUP BY AccountId

Tags: apex, soql, aggregateresult

How could I get this object `Map<Id, List<Contact>>`

Using an SOQL query similar to this:

```
Map<Id, List<Contact>> contactMap = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>(
                                      [SELECT AccountId Id, FirstName, LastName 
                                      FROM Contact
                                      WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds 
                                      GROUP BY AccountId]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That type of construct is not supported. You would end up with a `Map<Id, AggregateResult>` instead. Using a GROUP BY changes the query result in to an AggregateResult object. You may either build the map manually, or use a sub-query.

Note: if you use the sub-query method, and you expect more than about 2,000 contacts on a single account, you'll have to iterate over the list of contacts in a for-each loop.

## Sub-Query

```
Map<Id, Account> contactsByAccount = new Map<Id, Account>(
  [SELECT (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountIds]
);
```

To access the contacts, you'd have:

```
Contact[] accountContacts = contactsByAccount.get(accountId).Contacts;
```

Or:

```
for(Contact record: contactsByAccount.get(accountId)) {
  ...
}
```

---

## Manually Building Map

```
Map<Id, List<Contact>> contactsByAccount = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
for(Id accountId: accountIds) {
  contactsByAccount.put(accountId, new Contact[0]);
}
for(Contact record: [SELECT AccountId, FirstName, LastName FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountIds]) {
  contactsByAccount.get(record.AccountId).add(record);
}
```