# Which way efficiently fill a map

Tags: map, bestpractice

In a certain scenario I need to fill a Map<Id, List<...>>
In our example let's say All the contacts linked to their accountId (Map<Id,List> contactsPerAccountId)

I'm asking myself what is more efficient way to fill this list

**First option:**

```
List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact];
Map<Id,List<Contact>> contactsPerAccountId= new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
for (Contact c : contactList) {
    if (contactsPerAccountId.containsKey(c.AccountId)) {
        contactsPerAccountId.get(c.AccountId).add(c);
    }
    else {
        contactsPerAccountId.put(c.AccountId, new List<Contact>{c});
    }
}
```

**Second option:**

```
List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact];
Map<Id,List<Contact>> contactsPerAccountId= new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
for (Contact c : contactList) {
    if (!contactsPerAccountId.containsKey(c.AccountId)) {
        contactsPerAccountId.put(c.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
    }
    contactsPerAccountId.get(c.AccountId).add(c);
}
```

There is a ton of way to fill a map, if there is another, simpler and/or faster, please free to share

Comment: My first preference is to use a sub-query in cases like this, check out [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/238815/30493).

Comment: N.B. Trying to optimize little things like this is likely a _micro-optimization_. Unless you're dealing with a large quantity of these maps, there's likely going to be _no appreciable difference_ in any governor limit. In cases like these, the most "efficient" way to do this is probably the way _that involves the least typing_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to stats. Only `SOQL For Loops` will affect the memory. `If` and `else` statements wont give you any noticeable effects.

For eg:

```
List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact];
Map<Id,List<Contact>> contactsPerAccountId= new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
for (Contact c : contactList) {
    if (contactsPerAccountId.containsKey(c.AccountId)) {
        contactsPerAccountId.get(c.AccountId).add(c);
    }
    else {
        contactsPerAccountId.put(c.AccountId, new List<Contact>{c});
    }
}
```

**Gives a total heap size of 20414 bytes.**

[image]

Where as This code:

```
List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact];
Map<Id,List<Contact>> contactsPerAccountId= new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
for (Contact c : contactList) {
    if (!contactsPerAccountId.containsKey(c.AccountId)) {
        contactsPerAccountId.put(c.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
    }
    contactsPerAccountId.get(c.AccountId).add(c);
}
```

**Also gives heap size of 20414 bytes.**

[image]

But when you do `SOQL for loops`

```
Map<Id,List<Contact>> contactsPerAccountId= new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
for (Contact c : [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact]) {
    if (!contactsPerAccountId.containsKey(c.AccountId)) {
        contactsPerAccountId.put(c.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
    }
    contactsPerAccountId.get(c.AccountId).add(c);
}
```

**Then it gives a noticeable difference and the heap size is 4510 bytes**

[image]

The heap size is like reduced by 75%.

Comment: Heap isn't always accurate, because the length of time it takes to execute the code may cause artificially low values (Apex is weird that way). I'd be more concerned about overall time usage (these algorithms should be about the same). Also, in most cases, heap is usually the last thing you'll run out of, given all the governor limits. Still, nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're really concerned about performance, reduce the number of times you call containsKey/get. Here's a faster version:

```
Contact[] records = [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact];
Map<Id, List<Contact>> contactsByAccountId = new Map<Id, List<Contact>>();
for(Contact record: records) {
  contactsByAccountId.put(record.AccountId, new List<Contact>());
}
for(Contact record: records) {
  contactsByAccountId.get(record.AccountId).add(record);
}
```

This cuts out `containsKey` and the if statements, which turns out to be significantly faster than any other method.

Of course, as the comments say, if you need this level of optimization, you're probably already needing many more optimizations elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Filling map in either ways are almost similar.
One optimization I see here is in lesser lines of code for map creation and the other in not creating list just for iterating in a loop.

- For map creation, for if else scenario, we can use ternary operator to ease the assignment statement
- For iteration, when a list is declared and assigned it holds its value until it's
  scope ends, occupying heap space.
- Hence for iterating through loops, if possible, it's best to have the SOQL query in loop itself, instead of creating a list just for the loop. Though heap space issue may not impact any minimal code functionality, it's better to adopt this as a best practice

```
    Map<Id,List<Contact>> contactsPerAccountId= new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
    for (Contact c : [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact]) {
        contactsPerAccountId.containsKey(c.AccountId) ? 
        contactsPerAccountId.get(c.AccountId).add(c) :
        contactsPerAccountId.put(c.AccountId, new List<Contact>{c})
    }
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this. Maybe that's because the focus isn't on the `soql for loop` part  (which is probably the most important aspect)? Maybe because the ternary looks weird? I've tested this myself, and it is valid syntax, but there is some nuance here worth exploring. Both of the branches to the right of the `?` in a ternary need to be the same type (well, compatible types. `1 == 2 ? 1 : 2L` would work because `Integer` can be coerced into a `Long`). Map's `.put()` returns an `Object` (null, or the previous value if the map already has that key), and List's `.add()` returns null.

Comment: Both `Object` and `null` are "compatible" with pretty much every type (not sure if there are any edge cases), so the ternary is syntactically valid and works. This would work even if Map's `.put()` returned some non-null value. This might violate the Principle of Least Surprise (I think I've always seen ternaries used for assignment rather than as a more general "expression"), but that's about it.